# skip line powershell when you are doing a custum object in an array

Tags: arrays, powershell, line, skip

I would like to skip a line in the $array if there are certain words in the $array (current line)

```
 Get-Content -path $inDirFile | foreach{ # Read test.txt file and handle each line with foreach
                $array += [PSCustomObject]@{
                    If ([string]::IsNullOrWhitespace($array) -Or $array -Match "=" -Or $array -Match "PAGE" -Or $array -Match "MENUITM" -Or $array -Match "----" -Or $array -Match "USER") {
                    continue
                    }
                    else{
                    Field1 = $_.substring(1,12).Trim();
                    Field2 = $_.substring(13,11).Trim();
                    Field3 = $_.substring(25,2).Trim();
                    Field4 = $_.substring(28,2).Trim();
                    Field5 = $_.substring(31,2).Trim();
                    Field6 = $_.substring(34,2).Trim();
                    Field7 = $_.substring(41); # Substring from index 41 to the end of line
                    }
                }
}
```

Comment: you have to do your check before creating the custom object, just do `if(<match>){continue} else {$array +=...}`
i don´t get your usage of `$array` anyway, first you use it as array to hold your custom object but you also use it as string for your matching, which one is it?

Comment: Thanks Paul. I just tried it and still doesnt work. Did I write the match in the if right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main code issue is that you can't put your `if` statement inside the `[PSCustomObject]` constructor.

You're also trying to compare previous results when you use `$array`, you should use `$_` for everything which needs to reference the current line.

you can also make life much easier by:

- constructing a proper regex instead of using multiple `-match` statement
- negating the if statement to avoid using `continue`

The 'fixed' code would look something like this:

```
$array = @()
Get-Content $inDirFile | Foreach-Object {
    if (-not ( [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_) -or $_ -match "=|PAGE|MENUITM|----|USER" ) ){
        $array += [PSCustomObject]@{
            Field1 = $_.Substring(1, 3).Trim()
            Field2 = $_.Substring(5, 3).Trim()
            Field3 = $_.Substring(10,3).Trim()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Heidy no problem.